# IndexError: index 55 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 55 on Multi task text classification article Towards data science

Tags: python, indexing, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying to put into practice the code on Multi task text with `scikit-learn` classification presented by Susan Li https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Consumer_complaints.ipynb

Even in the Github repository provided, it raises an `Index error`, which i have not been able to solve. In her case the error does not come immediately (which is my case) but after the 4th case and other users seem to have the same issue.

i know it could come from the fact that the `numpy` array index starts at 0 which would make only 54 maximum index value...

1. Any hints on the original article error issue and how to solve it ?

By the way in my case `category_id_df.category_id` and `id_to_category` has 59 different values, all present in the confusion matrix. But i believe the test partition includes 4 new classes which are not present in the training set (`actual`) and which appear blank in the `conf_mat` values. This would make up for the difference Vs the 55 announced error. How could i overcome this programatically ?

```
232 for predicted in category_id_df.category_id :
233   for actual in category_id_df.category_id  :
--> 234     if predicted != actual and conf_mat[actual, predicted] >= 7:
235       print("'{}' predicted as '{}' : {} examples.".format(id_to_category[actual], id_to_category[predicted], conf_mat[actual, predicted]))
236       display(df.loc[indices_test[(target_test == actual) & (y_pred == predicted)]]    [['class1', 'doc_text']])

IndexError: index 55 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 55
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps using the `stratify` option with `train_test_split` could insure that both train/test splits have all the categories?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tested setting the labels property on the confusion matrix to the whole dataset...it seems to be working... Nevertheless i need to make some sanity check to make sure its taking the labels properly...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.